# Selenium not running when using [TestFixture(typeof(ChromerDriver))]

Tags: c#, selenium, nunit

So I've gone back to basics with a blank project to test this out, I'm trying to use the example...

```
[TestFixture(typeof(ChromeDriver))]
public class TestWithMultipleBrowsers<TWebDriver> where TWebDriver : IWebDriver, new()
{
    private IWebDriver driver;

    [SetUp]
    public void CreateDriver()
    {
        this.driver = new TWebDriver();
    }

    [Test]
    public void GoogleTest()
    {
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com/");
        IWebElement query = driver.FindElement(By.Name("q"));
        query.SendKeys("Bread" + Keys.Enter);

        Thread.Sleep(2000);

        Assert.AreEqual("bread - Google Search", driver.Title);
        driver.Quit();
    }
}
```

However it just does not run. If I remove the TestFixture typeof parameter though and set the driver manually it works fine.

```
[TestFixture]
public class TestWithMultipleBrowsers
{
    private IWebDriver driver;

    [SetUp]
    public void CreateDriver()
    {
        this.driver = new ChromeDriver();
    }

    [Test]
    public void GoogleTest()
    {
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com/");
        IWebElement query = driver.FindElement(By.Name("q"));
        query.SendKeys("Bread" + Keys.Enter);

        Thread.Sleep(2000);

        Assert.AreEqual("bread - Google Search", driver.Title);
        driver.Quit();
    }
}
```

Any ideas on why using TextFixture with a parameter would prevent the test from running? I've already checked over CPU settings and Resharper settings based on other posts.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After comparing NuGet packages with an old project looks like there may be an issue with the most recent version of NUnit. Downgraded to 2.6.4 all seems to be working fine.

Comment: The latest version of NUnit has test cases of its own very much like yours. See https://github.com/nunit/nunit/blob/master/src/NUnitFramework/tests/Internal/GenericTestFixtureTests.cs  Your code looks as if it should work. Try substituting some simpler class for the web driver as an experiment to show whether the driver introduces some complication we aren't seeing.